# Ffmpeg: How to capture audio and metadata simultaneously

Tags: node.js, sockets, audio, ffmpeg, pipe

I am developing a multi platform app for live audio streaming written in JS. The goal is to get the meters/volumes per channel while capturing audio from the sound card. This has to be done in one command since I get the error `device or resource busy` when firing multiple commands with the same input.

Capturing audio works fine using this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -i hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 -probesize 64 -rtbufsize 64 -reservoir 0 -fflags +nobuffer -hide_banner pipe:1
```

Getting the volume for the right channel works with this command (left channel is analog providing 0.0.1 to -map_channel):

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 -map_channel 0.0.0 -af ebur128=metadata=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.r128.M -f null pipe:1
```

**The question is how to combine these, providing a way to pipe the outputs correctly.**

As a first step, my current approach is to utilize the `file` argument of ametadata filter ([documenation here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#metadata_002c-ametadata)) and writing to a socket opened with the following JS code

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (c) { console.log('data:', c.toString()); });
});

server.listen('/tmp/test.sock');
```

like

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 -map_channel 0.0.1 -af ebur128=metadata=1,ametadata=mode=print:key=lavfi.r128.M:file=unix\:/tmp/test.sock:direct -f null -
```

but the socket receives no data and there is no error in ffmpeg.

Redirecting the output of the streaming command to the socket howerver works:

```
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -i hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 -probesize 64 -rtbufsize 64 -reservoir 0 -fflags +nobuffer -hide_banner unix:/tmp/test.sock
```

I am wondering what I am missing and whether I am on the right track alltogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is

`ffmpeg -y -f alsa -i hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 -filter_complex "asplit=2[out][stats];[stats]ebur128=metadata=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.r128.M:file=unix\:/tmp/test.sock:direct=1,anullsink" -map '[out]' -ac 2 -b:a 192k -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 -reservoir 0  -hide_banner pipe:1`

Notes:

- value has to be provided for filter options, so it's `direct=1`.
- the options `-probesize` `-rtbufsize` `-fflags +nobuffer` are all input-only options, and have no effect for output files.
- I believe the ebur filters scans and prints data for all channels by default. If you wish to use only one channel, add a pan filter immediately before the ebur128.
- your unix proto url should be fine but do check with a regular file or `-` to eliminate that variable.

Comment: Thanks, @Gyan! The command makes a lot of sense to me and I would have never figured that out myself. Sadly, I get "Option 'direct' not found". My ffmpeg version is 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. Should I update to 4.x?

Comment: Seems like the `=1` should be omitted with the `direct` option. Writing into a file works fine but unfortunately the socket receives no data. Any help on that is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: No, the destination is irrelevant. The value is required for any filter option.

Comment: I added direct only a few days ago, so you need a very recent git build

Comment: OK, I got the right version, [using the latest build from master](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). Still the socket receives no data.

Comment: What happens when you change destination to a pipe or file.

Comment: Writing to file works, I Found the issue after looking at the docs again: The `file` argument needs quotation marks when targeting not a plain file. The final command is: `./ffmpeg -y -f alsa -i hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 -filter_complex "asplit=[out][stats];[stats]ebur128=metadata=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.r128.M:file='unix\:/tmp/test.sock':direct=1,anullsink" -map "[out]" -ac 2 -b:a 192k -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 -reservoir 0 -hide_banner -nostdin pipe:1` Now I can go on and do things. Again, many thanks for your help!